# OnClick of RadioButton not working

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to change the text of a submit button on change of radio button .My code for html part is :

```
<input type="radio" onclick="check()" name="radio-view"  data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly"  id="segment1" value="Yes"/> 
<label for="segment1"  id="controls">
<span class="ui-btn-text-controls">Yes</span>
</label> 

<input type="radio" onclick="check()" name="radio-view" data-icon="segment-titlestyle-segonly" id="segment2" value="No" checked="checked"/>  
<label for="segment2" id="controls">
<span class="ui-btn-text-controls">No</span>
</label> 


<input type="submit" value="send" name="sendbutton" id="sendbutton"/>
```

My javascript code is as follow :

```
function check(){
var x;
x=document.f1.radio-view;
if(x[0].checked){
    document.f1.sendbutton.value="PROCEED";
}
else if(x[1].checked){
    document.f1.sendbutton.value="SEND";
}
}
```

But its not changing the test.What can be the reason for it?

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to address elements directly, use their names properly:

```
var x = document.f1['radio-view'];
```

... as you cannot access with the dot syntax the properties which names are not valid identifiers. `document.f1.radio-view` is treated as `document.f1.radio - view`, which apparently makes no sense.

But actually, I'd rather skip this part completely: if radio-button is clicked, it's definitely set as checked. So this...

```
<input type="radio" onclick="check(this)" ... />
...
function check(button) {
  document.f1.sendbutton.value = button.value === 'Yes' ? 'PROCEED' : 'SEND';
}
```

... should be quite enough, as this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSANC/) shows.

Comment: +1 Is it correct that `f1` is the `name` attribute of the `form` which contains these controls?

Comment: @kol Yes, that should be - for the whole question to make sense. )

Answer (score 0):

See Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tngbs/

```
//HTML
<form>
    <fieldset id="SPserviceStatus" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
                    <legend>Group<span class="required">*</span></legend>
                    <input type="radio"  name="ss" id="s1" value="Yes">
                    <label for="serviceStatus1">Yes</label>
                    <input type="radio"  name="ss" id="s2" value="No"  checked="checked">
                    <label for="serviceStatus2">No</label>
                </fieldset>
                        <input type='submit' id='submitBtn' value='SUBMIT' />
</form>

//JS
$("#s1").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").value = "Yes Clicked";
    return false;
});
$("#s2").click(function () {
    document.getElementById("submitBtn").value = "No Clicked";
    return false;
});
```